# How to subtract dates using OCONV

Tags: datastage

Background:
I am responsible for creating database extracts using datastage.  We have over five years of data with a CreatedDt (date datatype).  In the export query, I need to add a BETWEEN clause for CreatedDt.  Because the datastage job is generalized and parameterized, I need to have the dates calculated in the Sequence.

For example:  `Select * from tableA where CreatedDt BETWEEN <<start Date>> and <<End Date>>`

For one of those queries, I need to go back four months and get 3 months of data (skipping the previous month of now).  For example:

Assuming today's date: `02/22/2019`

I need:

```
Start Date: 10/01/2018
End Date: 12/31/2018
```

(basically skip on month back and go three months)

I know this means the following calculations are being used:

- Subtract from "Today" (twice)
- Go to Beginning of the Month (for the start date)
- Go to Last Day of the Month (for the end date)

I'm working with this formula:

```
OConv(Iconv(Date(),"D/YMD[4,2,2]") + 1), "D/YMD[4,2,2]")
```

From what I understand the '+1' represents adding/subtracting by day.  using the previously mentioned calculation issue.

I tried:

```
OConv(Iconv(Date(),"D/YM[4,2]") + 1), "D/YMD[4,2,2]")
```

Thinking that I was +1 a month, But this ended up years away from my target point.

I need to know how to do the operations I need on a given date. Or if there's another way, I'm more than open.

Thanks

Comment: Could you add more examples please and more details about what your goal is. I cannot see the relation from your formula to the example at all. Any chance to use db logic (SQL)?

Comment: I updated the question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Div` and `Mod` functions.

Example for 13 months ago:

```
OConv(Date(),'D-Y[4]')-Div(13,12):'-':OConv(Date(),'D-M[2]')-Mod(13,12):'-':oconv(Date(),'D-D[2]')
```

Answer (score 1):

StartDate
Oconv(Date() - 2, "D-YM[4,2]") : "-01"

EndDate
Oconv(Iconv((Oconv(Date(), "DY") : "-" : Oconv(Date(), "DM") + 4 : "-01") - 1, "DYMD"), "D-YMD[4,2,2]")

This end date calculation works for Jan-Aug.  Adjust the year and month maths and wrap in an If..Then..Else construct to handle the other months.

Answer (score 0):

> Because the datastage job is generalized and parameterized

does not mean you cannot do the calculation of the start date and end date in the database and select it from there. 
Databases usually offer lots of functions to do this date calculations making things a lot easier. You could run a SELECT selectng start and end date and write it to a file. In the sequence you could read that file and feed it to your job as a parameter.

If you stick to your datastage basic calcualtion I guess it will be a lot of steps.
You could do the month calculation manually in a transformer with IF THEN ELSE logic. One of the callenges is to get the end date (the start date will always be the 1.) but the [DaysInMonth](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZJPZ_11.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.parjob.dev.doc/topics/r_deeref_Date_and_Time_Functions.html) function could help you. DateFromComponents can then help you to reassemble the dates.

Answer (score 0):

I was working to get YearMonth variable (YYYYMM) with the availability to go a few months back in time. I am working on this formula for more than 1 business day, because in the sequence stage the functions are limited.
I have created the following function to get the YYYYMM variable when going a few months back in time:

```
((OConv(Date(),'D-Y[4]') - Div(12 + (2 - OConv(Date(),'D-M[2]')), 12)) * 100) + If (OConv(Date(),'D-M[2]') - Mod(2,12)) = 0 Then 12 Else  OConv(Date(),'D-M[2]') - Mod(2,12)
```

In the example above you will go 2 months back in time.

Hopefully some other Datastage engineers could use the code.